# Firefox - document.execCommand(‘cut’/‘copy’) was denied because it was not called from inside a short running user-generated event handler

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, copy-paste

I am developing a single-page app, I have a button on the page, when a user clicks the button I would like to make an ajax call to my server, and then copy the returned value (via callback) to the user's clipboard.

Each component works in isolation, but when I glue them together Firefox returns the following error:

> document.execCommand(‘cut’/‘copy’) was denied because it was not
>   called from inside a short running user-generated event handler

I would like to know the specifics of this error, but there is absolutely no information online; what are the limiting conditions that trigger this error, is it a stack depth, a timeout, etc?

Comment: The general idea is that the browser doesn't want you to manipulate the clipboard except in *direct* response to a user-generated event (such as a button click). But an Ajax call is asynchronous and so by the time the response is received the original click event is finished. You could perhaps display the result on-screen together with another button "Copy result to clipboard" (or similar). (That is nicer for the user, too, because it doesn't overwrite the clipboard without their realising it.)

Answer (score 19):

on firefox it only work with `click` handler, reference [Interact_with_the_clipboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard)

Answer (score 2):

Firefox will display the same error message if the manifest is missing the clipboardWrite permission.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to deal with this issue.

For me the solution was simply set async to false since the call is fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can [view link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript#30810322) about clipboard. Other way, you use synchronous. Example:

```
 $.ajax({
   method: "GET",
   async: false,
   url: {your_url},
   success: function(res) {
     let link= res.link;
     let temp_raw = $("<input>");
     $("body").append(temp_raw);
     temp_raw.val(link);
     temp_raw.select();
     document.execCommand("copy");
     temp_raw.remove();
   }
});
```