# Javascript clear clipboard after 1 minute

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I am currently copying a text to clipboard using the following code:

```
navigator.clipboard.writeText(element.value).then(function() {
    /* clipboard successfully set */
}, function() {
    /* clipboard write failed */
    console.log('Copy to clipboard failed!');
});
```

I need to clear the clipboard automatically after 1 minute if the data is successfully copied to the clipboard.

I tried using `setTimeout()` method but write to clipboard is failing when called from `setTimeout`.

Also, if I am using `execCommand('copy')` method, I am getting the error:
`document.execCommand(‘cut’/‘copy’) was denied because it was not called from inside a short running user-generated event handler.`

I am trying to make it work in Firefox.

The code I am trying to put inside setTimeout() is as follows:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText('').then(function() {
        /* Successfully cleared clipboard */
    }, function() {
        /* Failed to clear clipboard */
    }
}, 60000);
```

Comment: Are you using Firefox? Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41094318/firefox-document-execcommand-cut-copy-was-denied-because-it-was-not-calle

Comment: You can't manipulate the content of the clipboard without user's direct interaction.

Comment: Please include the `setTimeout` code that is failing.

Comment: @HarryCutts I have added the code which I am trying to execute inside setTimeout.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, I am trying to make it work with Firefox. What I am seeking is a work-around so it works with Firefox. For my web application, I need to clear the copied text from the clipboard after 1 minute.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox requires the command to come from a user event, such as click.  That's why it does not work from the handler. (You would not want some rogue javascript pasting data there, right?)

The exact wording is the command must called from

> a short running user-generated event handler

## Workarounds

### 1 Dummy `input element` and `document.execCommand("copy")`

Use a dummy input element with a single space as value, and a different API to select and copy it to the clipboard.

```js
function clearClipboardFromSetTimeout() {
  // This should work but does not
  //if (document.selection) document.selection.empty()
  //else window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()

  // Create a dummy input to select
  var tempElement = document.createElement("input");
  tempElement.style.cssText = "width:0!important;padding:0!important;border:0!important;margin:0!important;outline:none!important;boxShadow:none!important;";
  document.body.appendChild(tempElement);
  tempElement.value = ' ' // Empty string won't work!
  tempElement.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(tempElement)
}

function doIt() {
  navigator.clipboard
    .writeText("hello")
    .then(_ =>
      navigator.clipboard.readText().then(text => console.log("before", text))
    );

  setTimeout(() => {
    clearClipboardFromSetTimeout()
    navigator.clipboard.readText().then(text => console.log("after", text));
  }, 2000);
}
```

```html
<div>This will Snippet will not work in Firefox, but the <em>clearClipboardFromSetTimeout</em> method will.</div>

<button onclick='doIt()'>Set Then Clear In setTimeOut</button>
```

### 2 Flash

A hacky workaround is to use `Flash`: https://brooknovak.wordpress.com/2009/07/28/accessing-the-system-clipboard-with-javascript/

### 3 Tricking The Click Handler

There are also methods of holding the click context from a user event, and then using that to trigger another click event from your handler, that in turn calls your code.

### 4 Browser Refresh

I am not sure if a browser refresh will clear the clipboard, but if it does, you can save your state, to local-storage perhaps, and then force a refresh.

Comment: I would really prefer not to use Flash. Could you please elaborate on the second method of holding a click context and using it later?

Comment: @PratanuMandal I added another workaround, and will add a link to the one in question.

Comment: @PratanuMandal I found something.  Read my first workaround.  It is 'almost clear' because there is a space in the clipboard.

Comment: The code you have provided does not work for me. As a matter of fact, I had already tried this and this did not work before either. Can you please check?

Comment: Are you serving your page https?

Comment: Yes, I am serving my page as https

Comment: How does Firefox enforce that these actions come from a user event? Does the user event simply have to be in the "stack trace" of the write/readText calls?